# I can't craft leather from deer hide with Skyrim Requiem

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've got the latest version of Skyrim with all DLC.  When I load just Requiem alone (no other mods), I cannot craft leather from deer hide-- though I can craft it from leather armor.  If I disable the mod, I can.  I haven't found any patch or fix that repairs this.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does [this thread help](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/1040840-having-problems-crafting-leather/)?

Answer (score 3):

Without the basic smithing perk you cannot craft most items. Once you buy the crafting manual from a smith you will be able to spend a perk in smithing (you cannot put a perk in smithing without the manual in your inventory). Once you have the basic perk you will be able to craft leather as per usual.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the required smithing perk and the crafting journal which you can buy from most merchants.

Comment: A little more detail with this answer would be appreciated.  Is there anything special that you have to do after getting the perk, for instance.